# How to check item type Sitecore PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

How can I check if particular expected item  is content and datasources?

```
foreach($baseItem in $listOfPages) {
  $items += Get-Item $baseItem.Paths.FullPath 
  $items += Get-ChildItem $baseItem.Paths.FullPath -Recurse 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what you mean by "is content and datasources".

You can call

```
$baseItem.Paths.IsContentItem
```

that will return true is descendant of `/sitecore/content` item.

And you can

- `$baseItem.Template`
- `$baseItem.TemplateID`
- `$baseItem.TemplateName`

values to get more information about what kind of item that is.

Comment: Not always but datasources tend to have no layout.

Comment: To be sure if the item is content of page or page item itself

Answer (score 1):

So you can check if the item is a `Content` or `Datasource` using this way also.

```
$renderingInstance = Get-Rendering -Item $baseItem -Rendering $rendering
 
if($renderingInstance)
{
    Write-Host "content item"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "datasource item"
}
```

You can implement this logic with your code. Hope this will help.